# Передача параметров в функцию Python

Tags: python-3.x, функции, передача-параметров

Как мне известно, с версии python 3.8 передача аргументов в функцию может выглядеть таким образом

```
def func(pos1, pos2, /, pos_or_kwd, *, kwd1, kwd2):
```

где аргументы до "/" могут быть переданы только по позиции, после "/" - аргументы, которые могут быть переданы по имени и по позиции и после "*" аргументы, которые могут быть переданы только по ключевому слову.
Как при этом быть с аргументами со значением по умолчанию?

Comment: А что со значениями по умолчанию, какая тут связь? Проиллюстрируйте примером свой вопрос.

Comment: Например, мне нужно, чтобы в функцию можно было передать аргументы по умолчанию как по имени, так и по позиции. Такой код `def func(pos1, pos2 = 0, /, pos_or_kwd, *, kwd1, kwd2 = 0):`
выдает ошибку, тк после аргумента со значением по умолчанию у нас идет аргумент без значения по умолчанию

Comment: Ну, не надо так делать. Лучше вообще использовать только именованные аргументы, да и всё. А мешать одно с другим, да ещё и с дефолтными - это просто плохо.